# Is it possible to display flavor-text in a listbox and have that refer to a different value?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, directory, placeholder

I'm grabbing song files from a directory and storing them into a list, then I go through each item in that list and put the directory and other ID3-tag information into a class. Then a new list is created using that class and all directories are stored alphabetically.

What I have done is use the directory object from each one and placed that as the text in the listbox as I can't think of any other way to show only the Title of that track.

What I want to do is display flavor text, which is the Title of the track, and have that refer to the directory / the class it came from.

Comment: Listboxes can hold more than just strings.  If they are objects you create you can have them display whatever you want which may be just one property.  Kind of unclear from the question and lack of code

Comment: okay, so say I have a list of objects and I want to store these objects into the listbox, the text I want to display when the form is active is a property called '.Title'.

How would I store objects into the listbox and have each item refer to the .Title property?

Comment: the answer posted explains that (or the link does):  `myCBO.DisplayMember = "Title"`  the "object" would be a class and you could make it more effieicent using a List(of MyClass) as the listbox datasource rather than copying objects into it

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23679571/1070452) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties, and how they work.

MSDN Example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a link only answer, SO likes the info *here*