# Importing a CSV into a combobox, then changing other things in VB

Tags: vb.net, csv, import, combobox, streamreader

What I want to do is import a CSV file (called fwlist.txt), that looks like this:

> modelname,power type,pic,part number,firmware, option1, option 1, etc

End result, i would like a combobox that shows the modelname, and when the model name is selected from the pulldown, it updates various labels and text boxes on the form with other information.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim filename As String = "fwlist.txt"
Dim pwrtype As String
Dim pic As String
Dim partnum As String
Dim lineread As String
Dim FirmwareName As String



Private Sub ReadFirmwaresLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Load the items into the NameComboBox list.
    Dim ResponseDialogResult As DialogResult

    Try

        Dim FirmwareStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filename)
        ' Read all the elements into the list.
        Do Until FirmwareStreamReader.Peek = -1
            lineread = FirmwareStreamReader.ReadLine()
            Dim fields As String() = lineread.Split(",")
            FirmwareName = fields(0) 'Take First Field
            cbFW.Items.Add(FirmwareName)
            'Set Text labels based on position in line. 
            pwrtype = fields(1)
            pic = fields(2)
            partnum = fields(3)
            (...etc through options)
        Loop
        ' Close the file.
        FirmwareStreamReader.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' File missing.
        ResponseDialogResult = MessageBox.Show("File not Found!", "File Not Found",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If ResponseDialogResult = DialogResult.OK Then
            ' Exit the program.
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub cbFW_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbFW.SelectedIndexChanged
    lblPwrType.Text = pwrtype
    lblPic.Text = pic
    lblPartNum.Text = parnum
    ....etc thruogh options
End Sub
```

This code works, but only sort of.  If i select anything from the combo box, it only gives me the information from the very last line of the CSV file - even if its the first entry in the box.  I'm pretty sure it's something simple that I'm messing up.. anyone help?

Comment: Since each line has 7+ bits of data, create a class and store the info there.  A CBO can hold such Objects which will allow you to display whatever and keep the info together.  When they select one, the SelectedValue will be that object.  See [Storing Objects to a ListBox and Retrieve them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23679571/1070452)

Comment: thanks for the help... still having a hard time wrapping my head around the concept though.

Comment: If you store the FirmwareName in the CBO that is all it is going to have or know.  You'll have to write code to find all the other bits of data scattered hither and yon.  Create a class to store all the info about an item and put *them* in the CBO.  Now the SelectedItem will be *all* the info which you can display in other controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we read the lines into `Firmware` objects then we set this `List(Of Firmware)` as the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox`.

Then we handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ComboBox` which will get the currently selected firmware and loads its data to the `TextBox` controls.

This is a tested, working example below:

```
Public Class Firmware

    Public Property ModelName As String
    Public Property PowerType As String
    Public Property Pic As String
    Public Property PartNumber As String
    Public Property Firmware As String
    Public Property Option1 As String

End Class

Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

        Dim lines As String() = Nothing

        Try
            ' Read the file in one step
            lines = File.ReadAllLines("fwlist.txt")
        Catch ex As Exception

            Dim dialogResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(Me, "File not found! Would you like to exit program?", "Error reading file", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)

            If dialogResult = DialogResult.Yes Then
                Me.Close()
            End If

            Exit Sub

        End Try

        Dim firmwares As List(Of Firmware) = New List(Of Firmware)

        For Each line As String In lines

            Dim rawData As String() = line.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.None)

            ' Create Firmware object from each line
            Dim firmware As Firmware = New Firmware() With
            {
                .ModelName = rawData(0),
                .PowerType = rawData(1),
                .Pic = rawData(2),
                .PartNumber = rawData(3),
                .Firmware = rawData(4),
                .Option1 = rawData(5)
            }

            ' We store the read firmwares into a list
            firmwares.Add(firmware)

        Next

        ' Set the list as the data source of the combobox
        ' DisplayMember indicates which property will be shown in the combobox
        With cboModelNames
            .DataSource = firmwares
            .DisplayMember = "ModelName"
        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub cboModelNames_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboModelNames.SelectedIndexChanged

        RefreshForm()

    End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshForm()

        ' Get the selected item as Firmware object
        Dim currentFirmware As Firmware = DirectCast(cboModelNames.SelectedItem, Firmware)

        ' Refresh all the textboxes with the information
        With currentFirmware
            txtPowerType.Text = .PowerType
            txtPic.Text = .Pic
            txtPartNumber.Text = .PartNumber
            txtFirmware.Text = .Firmware
            txtOption1.Text = .Option1
        End With

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: hi @gabor i was hoping you could help me with my question. it's the same as this one but i am not using a firmware, link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429657/selecting-from-a-combo-box-with-data-from-csv-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Every time you set the value of a variable like `pwrtype`, its old value is thrown away and there is no way to get it back.  And even if you did save multiple values for each variable, you would need a way to figure out which value goes with the currently selected item in the combo box.  To resolve these two issues you need:

1. a way to group values from the same line together
2. a way to save *all* values read from the file, not just the most recent ones

Let's start with the first issue, grouping values together.  In the example code below, I created a Structure type called FirmwareInfo to serve that purpose.  Each FirmwareInfo has its own `pwrtype`, `pic`, etc.

The other piece of the puzzle that you are missing is a way to save more than one Firmware.  The easiest way to do this is to add each FirmwareInfo to the combo box's item list, instead of adding just the display string.  The combo box will convert each item to a string in the UI; the `ToString()` method tells it how you want this conversion to be done.

I haven't run this example code so I can't guarantee there aren't mistakes in there, but hopefully it's enough to show the general idea.

```
  Dim filename As String = "fwlist.txt"

  Structure FirmwareInfo
     Public pwrtype As String
     Public pic As String
     Public partnum As String
     Public FirmwareName As String

     Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return FirmwareName
     End Function
  End Structure

  Private Sub ReadFirmwaresLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     ' Load the items into the NameComboBox list.
     Dim ResponseDialogResult As DialogResult

     Try
        Dim FirmwareStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filename)
        ' Read all the elements into the list.
        Do Until FirmwareStreamReader.Peek = -1
           Dim lineread = FirmwareStreamReader.ReadLine()
           Dim fields As String() = lineread.Split(",")
           Dim info As New FirmwareInfo With {
              .FirmwareName = fields(0),
              .pwrtype = fields(1),
              .pic = fields(2),
              .partnum = fields(3)
              }
           cbFW.Items.Add(info)
        Loop
        ' Close the file.
        FirmwareStreamReader.Close()

     Catch ex As Exception
        ' File missing.
        ResponseDialogResult = MessageBox.Show("File not Found!", "File Not Found",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If ResponseDialogResult = DialogResult.OK Then
           ' Exit the program.
           Me.Close()
        End If
     End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub cbFW_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbFW.SelectedIndexChanged
     Dim currentInfo = DirectCast(cbFW.SelectedItem, FirmwareInfo)
     lblPwrType.Text = currentInfo.pwrtype
     lblPic.Text = currentInfo.pic
     lblPartNum.Text = currentInfo.parnum
     ' ....etc through options
  End Sub
```