# selecting from a combo box with data from csv in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

I have a .csv file that I load in a combo box inside a data grid view. My csv is like this:

```
prodname,prodcode,amt
prodname1,prodcode1,amt1
prodname2,prodcode2,amt2
```

`prodname` is what I am displaying in the combobox inside the datagridview.

What i want is when I select `prodname1`, `prodcode1` and `amt1` will be displayed on the same row in the data grid view. I am just starting to fumble around in vb.net and will be grateful if someone help me.

This is what I have for now:

```
    Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    cmb.HeaderText = "Product Name"
    cmb.Name = "cmb"
    DataGridView2.Columns.Add(cmb) 'code for a combobox column in datagridview

    Dim filename As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    filename = "/file/path/here"
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(filename)

    Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
    dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)), _
                         New DataColumn(newline(1))})
    While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
        newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(",")
        Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        cmb.Items.Add(newline(0))
        newrow.ItemArray = {newline(1)}
        dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
    End While
    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
```

---

UPDATE:

I updated my code as per Alex's answer but I still get an error.

```
    Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    cmb.HeaderText = "Product Name"
    cmb.Name = "cmb"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)

    AddHandler DataGridView1.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1_OnCellValueChanged
    AddHandler DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1_OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

    Dim filename As String

    filename = "/path/to/file"
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(filename)

    Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
    dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)), _
    New DataColumn(newline(1))})

     While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
        newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
        Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        cmb.Items.Add(newline(0))
        'newrow.ItemArray = {newline(1)} 
        dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
        dicItems.Add(newline(0), newline.Skip(1))
    End While
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_OnCellValueChanged(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Dim changedCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count
            dt.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item(i) = dicItems(changedCell.Value.ToString)(i) **error here**
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```

- he used semi-colon on his sample, but i am sticking to my comma. :)

The error says `Cannot find column 2` or when I tweak something, the error becomes `The given key was not present in the dictionary` on the same line

[image: Here is my csv file done in Excel]

Answer (score 0):

You need two new Event Handlers:

```
AddHandler DataGridView1.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1_OnCellValueChanged
AddHandler DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1_OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
```

The first is to recognize if the cell value of your combobox has changed.
The latter is to fire the `OnCellValueChanged` when you click on a combobox item (default behavior is that the event is only fired after you leave the cell).
Put that code in the Forms constructor or `Load` event handler.

Additionally you have to store which `prodname` has which details (e.g. `prodname1` => `prodcode1,amt1`). In my example I did this with a `Dictionary<Key: string => Values: IEnumerable<string>`.

```
Class Form1
   Private dicItems As New Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable(Of String))
   Private dt As New DataTable
   ...
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
        newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
        Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        cmb.Items.Add(newline(0))
        dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
        'Fill Dicitonary here. Key: newLine(0), values: newLine(1,2,...n)
        dicItems.Add(newline(0), newline.Skip(1))
     End While
   End Sub
```

The code of the event handlers are pretty straight forward:

```
  Private sub DataGridView1_OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
             DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        End If
     End sub
```

=> Fire the `CellValueChangedEvent` via Commiting the current combobox item change.

```
Private sub DataGridView1_OnCellValueChanged(s As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Dim changedCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count 
            dt.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item(i) = dicItems(changedCell.Value.ToString)(i)
        Next        
    End If
End sub
```

=> Check if the combobox has changed (`ColumnIndex = 0`) and get the changed cell.
Lookup in the dictionary to find the corresponding `prodcode,amt` with the given key (`prodname`).
Set the new value in the `DataTable` (you have to make `dt` a class field instead of a variable in your Load method).

Comment: hello! thank you for the reply. however i have follow up questions, this code is giving me a warning `newline.Skip(1)` and when i run the program, nothing is displaying in my dgv. and second, `The given key was not present in the dictionary.` when i select something in the combobox. it's o this line `dt.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item(i) = dict(changedCell.Value.ToString)(i)`

Comment: Okay I figured out the newline.skip part. There's still error in this. `The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Comment: In this case `changedCell` has a value which you haven´t added into the dictionray before. Put breakpoints in `dicItems.Add(newline(0), newline.Skip(1))` and `changedCell.Value.ToString` to see what is happening. Maybe you have an empty line in your text file? Btw with the demo data you provided in your question I don´t get any error.

Comment: Additionally: I removed the line `newrow.ItemArray = {newline(1)}` since it is not neccessary. Check if you removed it also.

Comment: yes i did removed it. i did indicate that i am using a .csv file. does it make a difference, since i think you used a text file?

Comment: Did you create the csv on your own or was it created by a tool, e.g. Excel?

Comment: i created it in excel then saved it as .csv file. is that wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117578/discussion-between-alex-b-and-predator).